# Tomcat server is running through Eclipse, But my app homepage is throwing a 404 error

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to build a Web app(Java, SpringMVC, Hibernate) of my own and I am pretty new to developing from scratch.
The sample project is done. Tech specs: Maven, Eclipse Oxygen IDE, Tomcat 9.
When I right Click Project -> Run as -> Run on Server i am getting the below error:

> Description: The origin server did not find a current representation
>   for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Same happens when I hit the URL(http://localhost:8080/mavenWebApp/getAllCountries) explicitly in a browser:

However, when I hit the Tomcat default page(http://localhost:8080) it works ok.

My Controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getAllCountries", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=application/json")
public String getCountries(Model model) {
    List listofCountries = countryService.getAllCountries();
    model.addAttribute("Country", new Country());
    model.addAttribute("listOfCountries", listofCountries);
    return "countryDetails";
}
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

I have a countryDetails.jsp in WEB-INF/views/ folder.

My complete web.xml

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationcontext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
     <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
     </servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have done the bean configurations in spring-servlet.xml, hence applicationcontext.xml in this case is a empty file that I created for the sake of it.

Please let me know if you want me to paste any other part of my code.
Oh and, server logs are not being updated in the otherwise usual Tomcat-Installation-Folder/logs. I am not sure why.

P.S. I have tried, switching the server properties -> General -> Workspace Metadata to /Servers/Tomcat v9.0 Server
And almost all other solutions provided previously out of which none of the seemed to work.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are asking

Comment: My tomcat server is up and running and the default page is loading fine as well. But when I try to run my project it throws me 404 error with Description: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Comment: Could someone please provide a hand? This is my first project and seems like I have hit a deadend.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, if the Option "Build automatically" is not set, the servlet may not compile. Building the project manually and restarting the server may solve the problem.

Comment: The build automatically is ticked. But it doesn't seem to solve my problem.